# Hallar cuántas <td> contienen cierto texto

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla donde cada `<td>` contiene cierto texto, como se ve en este html:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr><td>00:00 - 00:01</td><td>00:30 - 13:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 13:03</td><td>00:30 - 14:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 22:45</td><td>00:00 - 00:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 00:09</td><td>00:30 - 15:50</td></tr>
</table>
```

Y necesito hallar cuántas de esas `<td>` contienen el texto que comience con "00:00 - 00:", he intentado de dos formas, como se aprecia en el script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(Principal);
    function Principal(){
      var forma1 = $('[text^="00:00 - 00:"]').length;
      var forma2 = $('td [text*="00:00 - 00:"]').length;
      console.log(forma1);
      console.log(forma2);
    }
</script>
```

Los console.log deberían arrojar el número 3 en este caso, pero no me funciona, probé con `content` y `val` en el lugar en donde puse `text`, pero no me funciona.

Al parecer esa no es la forma de localizar el texto que contienen las td.

¿Alguna idea de cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Estás usando un [selector de atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo) para buscar un atributo que no existe, estas buscando un atributo llamado `text` que contiene el valor `00:00 - 00:`

Comment: Si no fuese una condición "*que comience con*", podrías usar [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) --> `$('td:contains("00:00 - 00:")').length` ... De lo contrario, hay que usar [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) o verificar cada uno como en la solución aceptada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De una manera más sencilla, puedes usar el selector de jQuery [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) que sí te permite seleccionar dependiendo del contenido de un elemento. En tu caso particular si quieres todas las celdas (`td`) que contengan el texto "00:00 - 00", tu selector sería algo como esto:

```
$("td:contains(00:00 - 00)")
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
alert($("td:contains(00:00 - 00)").length + " celdas contienen la cadena '00:00 - 00'")
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr><td>00:00 - 00:01</td><td>00:30 - 13:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 13:03</td><td>00:30 - 14:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 22:45</td><td>00:00 - 00:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 00:09</td><td>00:30 - 15:50</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias, una solución bastante simple.

Answer (score 4):

La consulta jQuery que deseas podría ser la siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(Principal);
function Principal(){
  var forma = $('td:contains("00:00 - 00:")').length;
  alert(forma);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr><td>00:00 - 00:01</td><td>00:30 - 13:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 13:03</td><td>00:30 - 14:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 22:45</td><td>00:00 - 00:30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>00:00 - 00:09</td><td>00:30 - 15:50</td></tr>
</table>
```

Como puedes ver, usando el selector [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), no es necesario hacer iteraciones.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas,

Te paso un script que acabo de hacer rapidito que me ha funcionado.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(Principal);
        function Principal(){
            var contador = 0;
            var cadena = '00:00 - 00:';
            $("td").each(function() {
                var contenido = $(this).html();
                    if( contenido.indexOf(cadena) >= 0){
                              contador += 1;
                            }
                }); 
            console.log(contador);
        }
    </script>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto :D